# PowerShell: ConvertTo-HTML Writing Output to One Line

Tags: powershell

I've been using PowerShell to create an HTML report using concatenated `ConvertTo-HTML` commands before writing the output to a file.  The cmdlet outputs have been broken into newlines until today.  Now the output of each cmdlet is on one line, making the end result a single line with over 8,000 characters.  I tried running the `ConvertTo-HTML` cmdlets separately by commenting the other ones out, but the result is still on one line.  I have run it from both the PowerShell terminal and within ISE.  Rebooted as a sanity check and I have the same issue.  Weirdly, if I copy one of the cmdlets and paste it in ISE and run it, it *does* format it properly with new lines.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

My `$PSVersionTable` output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1682
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1682
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

**EDIT (2022-08-30)**

Code example of how I'm using `ConvertTo-HTML`.

```
    $dac = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $AssessedInstance -Query "
        SELECT [state_desc] AS [Current Status]
        FROM sys.tcp_endpoints
        WHERE [name] = 'Dedicated Admin Connection'
    "
    $dacHTML = $dac | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment `
        -Property "Current Status" `
        -PreContent "<h3>Dedicated Administrator Connection</h3>" `
        -PostContent $dacText #String defined earlier in the code

   $html += $dacHTML

   #Much later...

   $html = ConvertTo-Html -Body "$html" -Header "$Header"
   $html | Out-File "$OutFilePath" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I have not changed how I've been doing the `$html` concatenation.

Comment: How are you saving the result of ConvertTo-Html? Show us some of your code

Comment: +1 on seeing more of your code/attempt. You may have made a change to how you are doing your concatenation and don't remember/realize what happened. Simply saying you've been using `ConvertTo-Html` and it worked fine before and now it doesn't, doesn't really give us much to work with in regard to helping you.

Comment: I've added a snipped with how I'm invoking `ConvertTo-Html` and how I write the final result out to a file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PowerShell module that can do this called PSParseHTML which has a function called Format-HTML. You might want to review the source of the module to see how it works. https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSParseHTML/blob/master/Public/Format-HTML.ps1

Comment: This is a great option, but it would help to include a code usage sample in the Answer.